# /page/2/ doesn't work on category page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm busy with this for two days now. I have the following setup in Wordpress:

Permalinks:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Files (among others):
category-blog
category-podcast
category-ebooks

Created categories:
blog (standard)
podcast
ebooks

The links site.com/blog, site.com/podcast and site.com/ebooks work, but when I go to site.com/blog/page2/ the page can't be found. Same problem with the other category pages.

I can see the posts in the category, but can't access page 2 etc.

When I create a new post type it works, but not for the standard Wordpress posts. Also, I don't want to create a new post type but want to use categories.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
<?php  
    function paginated_category( $query ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            if ( $query->is_category() ) {
                $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
            } 
        } 
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'paginated_category' );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can try it tomorrow evening. I'll post a reply here when I have tested it. I suppose I can change 2 to any number I like?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. It shows the right number of posts in the category (2 in this case), but site.com/blog/page/2/ doesn't work. It seems to only work when I use a category base, like for example the base "blog", but then my links look like site.com/blog/blog/rest-of-the-link/. I would like to have the links look like site.com/blog/rest-of-the-link/

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution (after days of search) which seems to work:

[Fix 404 errors](https://www.bamboomanchester.uk/fix-404-errors-wordpress-pagination/)